# Tkinter - Calling a Function With A Keybind Adds A Variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

When I call a method with a KeyBind in Tkinter, e.g. `parent.bind('<Return>', self.login)`, when it calls `self.login` it appears to add a second variable, as if it were calling `self.login(var)`.

Although it varies, when I had it print `var`, it printed `<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x028C5558>`. Now I'm guessing this is either the item it was called from, or the event that called it, but when I had it do it multiple times, it showed the same thing.

The problem was simply solved by adding `var='asdf'` in all of the methods called by keybinds, but does this have an important purpose? Is there something I need to be putting in my methods? If else, what is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a binding fires, it always passes an object representing the event that caused the callback to be called. This has information such as the x,y coordinate of the event, the key that was pressed, a timestamp for when the event occurred, etc.

You don't always need this information, but it is always given to the callback. You need to add an `event` keyword argument:

```
def myCallback(event=None):
    <your code here>

...
someWidget.bind("<1>", myCallback)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the very useful [Effbot Tkinter guide](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), it states the following (emphasis mine):

> ```
> widget.bind(event, handler)
> ```
>
> If an event matching the `event` description occurs in the widget, the
>   given `handler` is called with **an object describing the event**.

You see this as `<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x...>`. It has various attributes, describing what's happened (e.g. `x` and `y` location of the mouse pointer, the `widget` itself, etc.).

Comment: I can see how this could be useful, but is there some organized way to read it? And if not, what is the format it is read in?

Comment: @BenMorris I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: you said it contains various attributes, how can you read those?

Comment: @BenMorris the same way you'd read the attributes of any object - `objectname.attrname`. If you name the parameter `event` and want the horizontal mouse position, it'd be `event.x`, for example.